# graphql create mutation returns status 400

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm trying to register a user, I can do it in apollo sandbox / studio but not in the browser with the mutation request. I've checked the official docs and multiple tutorials but can't find what I'm doing wrong. Please help!

```
const CREATE_USER_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation CreateUser($username: String!, $password: String!){
        create_user(username: $username, password: $password){
            username
            password
        }
    }
`
const Register = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
    const [pass1, setPass1] = useState('')
    const [pass2, setPass2] = useState('')
    const [create_user, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(CREATE_USER_MUTATION)

    const registerCheck = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (pass1 == pass2) {
            create_user({
                variables: {
                    username: username,
                    password: pass1
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

error:
`Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400`

edit: my resolver and schema just incase:

```
        create_user: async (_parent, args, ctx) => {
            const result = await ctx.prisma.user.create({ data: { username: args.username, password: args.password } })
            if (!result)
                return {
                    success: false,
                    message: "failed to create user"
                }
            if (result) {
                return {
                    success: true,
                    message: 'user created: ' + result.username,
                    user: result
                }
            }
        }
```

schema:

```
    type User {
        id: String
        name: String
        email: String
        username: String
        password: String
        image: String
        assigned_projects: [Project]
    }

    type Mutation {
        create_user(username: String!, password: String!): UserCreatedResponse
    }
```

Comment: If you are on chrome, you can download the GraphQL Network Inspector plugin. Restart chrome, open devtools, execut the query and you can see the exact problem, what variables are sent and where the error might be.  Or you can console.log the error and see whats the issue

Answer (score 0):

In your *typeDefs* you expect a `UserCreatedResponse` object back from the mutation.

```
create_user(username: String!, password: String!): UserCreatedResponse
```

How is that object defined?

Then in your resolver you return:

```
return {
  success: true,
  message: 'user created: ' + result.username,
  user: result
}
```

which suggests that `UserCreatedResponse` is typed as:

```
type UserCreatedResponse {
   success: Boolean
   message: String
   user: User
}
```

But in your client mutation you have:

```
const CREATE_USER_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation CreateUser($username: String!, $password: String!){
        create_user(username: $username, password: $password){
            username
            password
        }
    }
```

Which doesn't line up with your *typeDefs*. I'd expect:

```
const CREATE_USER_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation CreateUser($username: String!, $password: String!){
        create_user(username: $username, password: $password){
            success
            message
            User {
                username
                password
            }
        }
    }
```

Also surprised that `password` is part of your `user` type and that you'd be returning it to the client but that's a separate issue.